# Optimal pure state decomposition of bipartite mixed states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Suppose I have a 2-qubit mixed state given by $\rho$ whose concurrence is $C$. I am interested in finding the optimal pure state decomposition of $\rho=\sum_{i=1}^4 p_i|\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|$ such that $C(\psi_i)=C$. Is there any way to get this decomposition or at least any relationship between $|\psi_1\rangle, |\psi_2\rangle$ and so on?

I tried taking $C=2\sqrt{\lambda_0\lambda_1}$ where $|\psi_i\rangle=\sqrt{\lambda_0}|0^i\rangle|0^i\rangle+\sqrt{\lambda_1}|1^i\rangle|1^i\rangle$, where $|0^i\rangle=\alpha_i|0\rangle+\beta_i|1\rangle$ and $|1^i\rangle=\beta_i^\ast|0\rangle-\alpha_i^\ast|1\rangle$ with $|\alpha_i|^2+|\beta_i|^2=1$. However, I couldn't proceed from here.

---

[***Cross-posted on qc.SE***](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/35599/55)

Comment: The decomposition you write for $\rho$ seems erroneous.

Comment: Sorry my bad! I have corrected it now.

Comment: Does such a decomposition exist?

Comment: The concurrence of pure states has to be equal to ‘$C$’ as it’s a convex function and number of pure states in decomposition is 4 as mentioned in Wooters’s paper

Comment: Might this be a better question for [quantumcomputing.se]?

Comment: @Aniket Making this more self-contained might help.

Comment: ... and crosslink your crossposts, please.